# How to edit Visual Studio CUDA nvcc.exe Command Line

Tags: cuda

I need to edit the Visual Studio command line for the NVidia CUDA compiler nvcc.exe build step, however it can not be edited.

I'm sure this question has been asked but it is tricky because if I search for anything with "Command Line" it returns hundreds of articles on how to just use external command line compiling, not from inside VS.

NVidia CUDA *.cu files have a different command lines for both the compile and link steps, and if I go to my Visual Studio project properties, Configuration Properties, CUDA C/C++, Command Line, neither can be edited.

I searched for some of the command line text in the NVidia toolkit folder and found this.

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions\CUDA 10.1.props

This file seems to define the build step, but if I edit it and restart Visual Studio, nothing changes. It seems to have been used only during the CUDA installation. I've tried opening various VS files such as project.user but the nvcc command line is not defined anywhere in the solution files. Also, it's no good changing the start up project definition because I need to be able to add CUDA GPU processing to my existing project.

Have any of you Visual Studio guru's been able to edit the Command Line for third party compilers and if so, how? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You just edit it like you do with any other build tool in Visual Studio: by editing the properties. The command line category in the project properties is really just there to show you what the command is going to look like based on the properties you set. The whole point of having properties is that you just set properties and have the IDE translate those properties into the correct command line for the specific tool rather than specifying a command line directly…

The `.props` file of a build customization sets up the default properties to use for the item types associated with that build customization. The one actually being used should be installed in the MSBuild directory, e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations`. I would advise against editing that file directly though, as it sets up system-global defaults. If you want to change the defaults for your project, simply edit the CUDA C/C++ properties of the project (i.e., select the project in the solution explorer and edit its properties rather than the properties of an individual .cu file).

Properties in Visual Studio are built up in layers (strictly speaking, we're talking about item metadata here rather than properties, but that's a minor technicality which should be irrelevant here). At the bottom, you have the default property definitions which the project imports for all its build tools. On top of those, you have the project-wide property definitions. And each item (file) within the project can have its own property definitions on top of that. The set of properties for each item is the combination of all properties defined for this item type (e.g., a CUDA C/C++ file) as well as any item-specific definition, where the last definition overwrites previous ones. When you see a property rendered in bold font in the Visual Studio properties dialog, that means that that particular property value is overwritten at that level. Non-bold properties are inherited from layers beneath. So, for example, a bold property in the project properties means that setting is overwritten on top of the default property coming from the build integration. A bold property at the item level means that property is overwritten for this item on top of the project-wide properties. Further customization is possible, e.g., by defining your own property sheets, which allow you to add your own layers of property definitions. Property sheets are also standalone files which can be imported into multiple projects, e.g., to share common settings. Simply open the Property Manager (View > Property Manager) to see all the individual property sheets in your project at the moment and, e.g., add your own…

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. That makes perfect sense. I examined the nvcc command line in more detail and each parameter is indeed a function of editable properties accessible elsewhere in the properties pages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer to my own question here after resolving it so if others have the same problem they will be able to find a simple solution here.

As you can see above the nvcc.exe compiler command line is not editable because it is simply a function of various other editable properties.

However, the whole reason I wanted to edit the nvcc command line in the first place was because of the following compiler error:

1>nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified

The NVidia CUDA nvcc.exe compiler was working correctly for my Visual Studio Debug build but failed every time with the above error for any Release build.

I anticipated that to solve this I would have to edit the nvcc.exe command line, however this turned out not to be the case, for the following reason.

When I deleted all spaces in my Visual Studio Configuration Build names the problem completely disappeared!

Apparently the nvcc.exe compiler can not handle spaces in configuration build names despite the use of double quotes around them in all command line references. This problem therefore is probably something internal to the nvcc compiler and was never found by NVidia simply because most people are smart enough not to use spaces in their build names.

Bottom line, do not use spaces in your VS configuration build names and you will not have this problem with the NVidia CUDA compiler.